# When will a thread woken via a condition variable run?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

When I wake up a thread waiting on a condition variable while holding the corresponding mutex, can I assume that the woken thread will run after I release the mutex and before anyone else (myself included) can lock the mutex again? Or can I only be sure that it will run at some point in the future?

To be precise, assume that I have the following functions.

```
bool taken = false;
int waiting = 0;

pthread_mutex_t m;   // properly initialised elsewhere
pthread_cond_t c;

void enter() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    // Is `taken || (waiting == 0)` guaranteed here? 
    while (taken) {
        ++ waiting;
        pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
        -- waiting;
    }
    taken = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}

void leave() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    taken = false;
    if (waiting > 0) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&c);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

(This is a toy example, not meant to be useful.)

Also assume that all threads are using these functions as

```
enter()
// some work here
leave()
```

Can I then be sure that directly after acquiring the mutex in `enter()` (see comment in the code), if `taken` is false `waiting` has to be zero? [It seems to me that this should be the case, because the woken thread will assume to find the state that the waking thread has left behind (if the wake-up was not spurious) and this could otherwise not be guaranteed, but I did not find it clearly worded anywhere.]

I am mainly interested in the behaviour on (modern) Linux, but of course knowing whether this is defined by POSIX would also be of interest.

Note: This may have already been asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212960/can-it-be-assumed-that-pthread-cond-signal-will-wake-the-signaled-thread-atomi), but I hope that mine is clearer.

---

After `t0` does `pthread_cond_signal`, `t1` is no longer waiting for the condition variable, but it is also not running, because `t0` still holds the mutex; `t1` is instead waiting for the mutex. The thread `t2` may also be waiting for the mutex, at the beginning of `enter()`. Now `t0` releases the mutex. Both `t1` and `t2` are waiting for it. Is `t1` handled in a special way and guaranteed to get it, or could `t2` get it instead?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44417229/2989411) - maybe it would give you some insights.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski, thanks for pointing out the other question.

Comment: @Miket25, I probably could have stated it more clearly. After `t0` does `signal`, `t1` is no longer waiting for the condition variable, but it is also not running, because `t0` still holds the mutex, it is instead waiting for the mutex. The thread `t2` may also be waiting for the mutex, at the beginning of `enter()`. Now `t0` releases the mutex. Bother `t1` and `t2` are waiting for it. Is `t1` handled in a special way and guaranteed to get it, or could `t2` also get it?

Comment: In general, there could be multiple threads waiting on a single condition.  There's no guarantee which of those threads will run after a `pthread_cond_signal()`.  If other threads are using the mutex separately from the condition, there's no guarantee whether one of those threads will get the mutex first.  That's why it is crucial to check that the condition a thread is waiting on holds after getting the mutex.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that makes total sense, but I had often only read that you should check the condition because of spurious wake-ups. These are not a problem here, because the woken thread actually checks the condition. However, with what you are saying, it would still be an error here if at the line of the comment I argued as followed: "If `taken` is false here, anyone who has entered has exited and on exit woken up a waiting thread, so no thread can be waiting." I am getting convinced now, but at first I thought that I might be paranoid.

Comment: In the case of Windows with Windows native mutexes, in the testing I've done, the order in which threads ask for a lock determines the order that the threads will waken when the mutex is unlocked. In other cases, including Windows using non-native mutexes, the ordering by lock request did not occur, and it would be possible for the same thread to repeatedly get the lock, even though other threads already had pending lock requests. If the OS includes a priority boost feature for threads stuck waiting, then the priority boosted thread would get the lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comment, Carsten, that cleared it up.

No, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522858/understanding-of-pthread-cond-wait-and-pthread-cond-signal) for more reference. Given your example, `t2` could acquire the mutex before `t1` and a race condition may occur leading to unexpected outcomes.

Reiterating, `t0` may initially have the mutex and be in the while loop holding on the line `pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);`and the mutex is released atomically [reference](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait). `t1` could call `leave()` acquiring the mutex signaling the condition `c`, and then release the mutex. `t0` will prepare to run `--waiting` by trying to acquire the now-freed mutex by `t1`, but it can become context switched by the OS. Some other thread `t2` waiting on the mutex can grab it and run `enter()` causing undesired outcomes, see [non-reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)#Relation_to_thread_safety). `t2` then releases the mutex. `t0` may swaps back only to see values have been mutated.

Comment: Thanks, your answer probably states the problem more clearly than my question ;) I would feel more comfortable if it cited something to that effect, though.

Comment: I can see your difficulty finding an answer this. I had a hard time find verification myself. [Reference](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-cv.pdf) First paragraph on pg.3 "hints" that `t0` does need to "re-acquire" the mutex and that it is not treated specially. I'll see if I can find more.