Correct use of boost notify_all in interprocess communication on linux kernels
tl;dr should boost notify_all() be used before or after releasing the lock?
Wikipedia has this comment on signal (in my view similar to broadcast):

it is often also acceptable to release the lock before signalling. Depending on the threading implementation, the ordering of this can have scheduling-priority ramifications. (Some authors[who?] instead advocate a preference for releasing the lock before signalling.) A threading implementation should document any special constraints on this ordering.

The std cpp implementation of the std::condition_variable calls notify_one after releasing the lock:
data = "Example data";
// send data to the worker thread
{
  std::lock_guard lk(m);
  ready = true;
  std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
}
cv.notify_one();

But when using the boost implementation we can find both variants in the internet (1, 2, 3, p. 127):
boost::interprocess::interprocess_sharable_mutex mutex;
boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition_any cond;

// Producer Process with variants A and B

void producerA() {
  const boost::posix_time::ptime abs_time = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::microseconds(maxLockTime.count());
  boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_sharable_mutex> lock(mutex, boost::interprocess::defer_lock);
  if (lock.timed_lock(abs_time)) {
    // Write data
    // ...
    cond.notify_all();  // <--- Notify all consumers
  }
}

void producerB() {
  const boost::posix_time::ptime abs_time = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::microseconds(maxLockTime.count());
  boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_sharable_mutex> lock(mutex, boost::interprocess::defer_lock);
  if (lock.timed_lock(abs_time)) {
    // Write data
    // ...
  }
  cond.notify_all(); // <--- Notify all consumers
}

// Consumer Process

void consumer() {
    const boost::posix_time::ptime abs_time = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::microseconds(maxLockTime.count());
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_sharable_mutex> lock(mutex, boost::interprocess::defer_lock);
    bool hasNewMessage = cond.timed_wait(lock, abs_time, [=]() { ... });

    // Read data

    lock.unlock();
}

Is there a definitive answer to which variant is preferred, either producerA or producerB. In my local tests both producer work accordingly, but in my question I am interested in worst case scenario where system is heavily loaded.
I ran both producer on my system, there was no notable difference visible.
But I am investigating a bug on another remote system where we observe infinite timeouts on the notify_all() function call.

"std cpp implementation" - that's just an example though

See also e.g. https://austin-group-l.opengroup.narkive.com/lKcmfoRI/predictable-scheduling-behavior-in-pthread-cond-broadcast (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/74653339/85371)

notify_all() should never have an infinite timeout itself, that method/function should return relatively fast, regardless of whether you do it while holding the mutex or not. (wait() may wait infinitely if not signalled properly.) If you release the lock before you signal, you might get into scheduling trouble in real-time contexts (SCHED_FIFO etc.) due to a lack of priority inversion. But in non-RT scheduling you should always be scheduled again as soon as if calling any other system call from your thread when using notify_all(), even under load and even if already unlocked.
